# Is it possible to orbit the viewport while transforming/selecting?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Can I orbit the viewport *while* transforming/selecting? For instance, by disabling the Middle Mouse Button's Axis Selection functionality?

Full explanation: 
Let's assume I've selected a mesh, pressed G to transform, selected Y axis by pressing Y, realised I can't see what I'm doing because Y axis is perpendicular to screen - now - I would like to orbit the view to see better without cancelling the transform operation.

By the looks of it, if MMB during the transform or select operation didn't invoke axis selection, it could perhaps still invoke orbiting viewport. But I can't find an option to disable MMB as axis selector shortcut.

Perhaps it's coded deeper somewhere that viewport repositioning and modelling operations are mutually exclusive - but I hope not!

Comment: There's a class of operators - modal operators - which allow this; for instance, the knife tool. As for current selection tools, I don't think it's possible. There _may_ be an addon for this and, if not, I'm sure one can be written.

Comment: There is not much need for this feature I suppose if you work in any 3d software package long enough. Artist would naturally be able to position the view so that whatever they want to translate or rotate to is pretty much in view. I have not found such function necessary at all.

Comment: I'd like to close the question because it's just hanging here. Can we agree that "No it isn't possible without programming a new tool, based on modal operators"?